# Button gets clicked two times in background when clicking second time

Tags: jquery

**I have following code in JQuery**

```
<script language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {            
        $('#btnSaveRole').click(function(){
            $('#btnFinalSaveRole').click(function() {                
                var $_Role          =   $('#txtRole').val();
                var data = {
                    "Role"          : $_Role
                };    
                $.ajax({
                    url:            'http://localhost:1234/AdminSystem1/public/SaveRole',
                    method:         "POST",
                    async:          true,
                    data:           JSON.stringify(data),
                    contentType:    "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (msg) {
                        $("btnSaveRole").unbind('click');
                        $("btnFinalSaveRole").unbind('click');

                    },
                    error: function (jqXHR) {
                        $("btnSaveRole").unbind('click');
                        $("btnFinalSaveRole").unbind('click');
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    });

</script>
```

Issue is when I click on same button `btnSaveRole` again, it get clicked two times.

In order to fix that I used below code in success and fail callbacks

```
$("btnSaveRole").unbind('click');
$("btnFinalSaveRole").unbind('click');
```

Am I missing anything?

Comment: Why do you have a click callback inside of a click callback?

Comment: @Devon Selectors are different. As I understand, button `save` is bound first. When it is clicked, button `final save` is bound. For example, like "Are you sure?" button. When the second button clicked, an AJAX is executed, after which both buttons are unbound.

Comment: As I try in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nccd9gqc/) and as i observe if how many I click the button 1(for example 3x) and I click the button 2 the alert will pop up 3x also(like how many click in button 1)

Comment: adding events inside other events = BAD IDEA. Each time you click, you add new events to the same element. It does not override them....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First click, you add an event to btnFinalSaveRole
Second click, you add another event to btnFinalSaveRole

So of course when you click btnFinalSaveRole, you will have two clicks. Since you clicked btnSaveRole twice.

jQuery click() does not override events, it appends it to a list.

So appending an event inside another is normally a bad idea. Better idea is to bind outside. If you need to make sure X is clicked first, than make a boolean.

```
var clicked = false;
$("#btnSaveRole").on("click", function(){
    clicked = true;
});
$("#btnFinalSaveRole").on("click", function(){
    if(clicked) {
        alert("yahoo");
    }
});
```

other option would be to unbind the event, not the best, but can work.

```
$("#btnSaveRole").on("click", function(){
    $("#btnFinalSaveRole").off("click.val").on("click.val", function(){
        alert("hmmmm");
    });
});
```

Comment: Or, he could just use .`one("click")` instead of .`click()`

Comment: @Tibrogargan: Please explain with an example.

Comment: @epascarello: Your solution is working fine. I will wait for Tibrogargan reply meanwhile and if I don't get better reply, your answer will be marked.Thank You.

Comment: @helper You didn't provide an [mcve] and I'm way too lazy to make one up.  I really don't feel that comfortable posting something I can't test

Answer (score 1):

Try this.  (No guarantees since I can't test it).  It demonstrates use of the `.one()` version of `.on()` that automatically unbinds once it's used

```
<script language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {            
        $('#btnSaveRole').on("click", function() {
            $('#btnFinalSaveRole').one("click", function() {                
                var $_Role          =   $('#txtRole').val();
                var data = {
                    "Role"          : $_Role
                };    
                $.ajax({
                    url:            'http://localhost:1234/AdminSystem1/public/SaveRole',
                    method:         "POST",
                    async:          true,
                    data:           JSON.stringify(data),
                    contentType:    "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                });
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Working perfectly. Question, In the comment section underneath my post(my question). @epascarello told that it is bad to add events inside other events. Your thoughts please.

Comment: It's bad because it can lead to things like events getting added twice, which is exactly what you ran into.  Remember, @epascarello said *normally* a bad idea, which is completely true.  There are circumstances where it makes sense, but they are generally not normal

Comment: upvoted for the solution. `on` and `one` combimation. Thanks.